# What does the name of the resource block represent in chef's log construct?

Tags: ruby, chef-infra

I am confused by the description of the 'name' element in [chef docs](https://docs.chef.io/resource_log.html).
Example code:

```
log 'message' do
  message 'This is the message that will be added to the log.'
  level :info
end
```

Why does **message** appear twice above?

What does it mean during each occurrence?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the doc just chose the resource block's name a little injudiciously. A better example might be:

```
log 'foo' do
    message 'Logging to foo'
    level :fatal
end
```

In this case, the log resource's name is `'foo'`, while the `message` argument dictates what message to log. If the `message` argument is left empty, it defaults to the value of `name` (in this case, `'foo'`). So, in this case:

```
log 'foo' do
    level :fatal
end
```

The literal text `foo` would get dumped to your logfile.

Comment: Thanks Sebastian. I have 2 doubts: (1) If both name and message are present, then the name only specifies the resource-name and is meant to be used for identification and notifications only, right? (2) The resource-name does not signify in any way the target of the message being logged, right?

Answer (score 1):

The name is the default value for the `message` property. If you specify the `message` explicitly then the name is only used for notification routing and de-duplication.